# when I run make menuconfig or make config how it works?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

In a new kernel package there is two config files inside  arch/x86/configs :

1. i386_defconfig  2. x86_64_defconfig

when I did make menuconfig, it generate .config file. But It has some default setting also. From where, it take these default setting ? Is it used one of these files or used from /boot directory or from some where else

same question for make config.

Answer (score 3):

No, It won't pick the config file from /boot

It first determines the processor/OS architecture from $MACHTYPE of your system unless you explicitly mention "ARCH=" variable like in "make ARCH=arm menuconfig",

say

echo $MACHTYPE

x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

Then based on the found architecture, it gets the apt defconfig file from arch/found_arch/configs/apt_def_config_file

Comment: from where I can find the $MACHTYPE variable. In which file this variable defined.

Comment: MACHTYPE is your bash variable, just do an echo $MACHTYPE, its populated by your bash

Comment: What happens if MACHTYPE is not set? Is there a default config file chosen in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The default settings are present as files in the filesystem.

Execute: `find . -name \*_defconfig` inside your kernel sources.

The config files present in in /boot were most likely created by one of the packages you installed and not by the kernel build process itself.